# Признаки глагола

Tags: морфология

Школьный учебник утверждает, что все возвратные глаголы являются непереходными. А как насчет "напиться чаю"?

При переходных глаголах существительное или местоимение может стоять, кроме В.п., в Р.п. без предлога: 1)при отрицании; 2)при указании на часть предмета (выпить чаю).

Comment: Похоже, что в какое-то время произошло изменение в падежах.  Мне почему-то кажется, что "напиться чаем" было бы более плавильно.

Comment: Однако в "Мойдодыре" именно так.

Comment: Я не спорю с нынешним употреблением. Оно есть, с ним спорить бесполезно.  Мне просто кажется, что это - тенденция упрощения языка, опростонародивание, обусловленное продвижением "культуры в массы" и обратной волной.

Comment: А Крылов тоже "продвигал культуру в массы"? "Наевшись желудей досыта, до отвала..."

Comment: Во-первых, оба примера - из стихов.  В них всегда дозволяется определённая свобода.  Строгим языком хорошие стихи писать затруднительно.  Во-вторых, многие примеры употребления тех или иных форм, даже у Розенталя, взяты из прямой речи, которую надо воспринимать в качестве образца с хорошей долей скептицизма.

Comment: Что же воспринимать в качестве образца, если не язык классиков? И что такое "строгий язык"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31328/discussion-between-natturtle-and-victor-bazarov).

Answer (score 3):

И всё-таки это непереходный глагол. Переходный -глагол со значением действия, направленного на предмет, изменяющего или производящего этот предмет - объект действия. Выпить воду, выпить воды - переходный.

А вот напиться - непереходный. Префикс на- и постфикс –ся обозначают в данном случае "наполненность чем-нибудь" и употребляются с родительным падежом количественного значения или вещественного сущ. Формы на –а принимают лексемы книжного характера и общеупотребительные, формы на –у – разговорные и вещественные сущ. (как, например, чаю- напиться чаю). Здесь важна количественная оценка самого действия:  субъект совершает какое-то действие столько, сколько он хочет, до такой  степени, что он больше не хочет совершать его. Состояние насыщения может наступить как в накричаться, накружиться, накупаться, накуриться, накушаться,  налакаться 'вдоволь, досыта полакать (о животных)', налакомиться,  нализаться 'вдоволь полизать', наломаться 'вдоволь поломаться, поиздеваться над кем-л.', налопаться 'наесться', наораться, напастись, напеться, написаться, напитаться 'наесться', напиться. Как видите, таких глаголов много, и все они непереходные.

Answer (score 2):

> ...все возвратные глаголы являются непереходными.

Не все лингвисты считают **все** возвратные глаголы непереходными.

[**Из Литневской:**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm#i7)

> Обычно возвратные глаголы являются непереходными — за редким
>   исключением: ***бояться, стесняться*** маму.

===

> А как насчет "напиться чаю"?

***Напиться*** -- непереходный глагол: у него **отсутствует способность иметь прямое дополнение в вин. падеже без предлога**, что не позволяет относить его к переходным.

Answer (score 0):

Напиться (чего) чаю - это Р.п, сравнить: выпить (что) чай - В.п.

Переходный глагол обозначает действие, направленное на объект, выраженный **беспредложным В.п**.. Исключение: купить книгу - не купить книги (**Р.п. при отрицании**).

Comment: Возможно, что так. В академической грамматике сказано, что объект выражается В.п. ,  реже  - Р. п.), но при отрицании Р.п.  является регулярным.

Comment: Но это ничего не меняет, так как Р.п используется как вариант, а основным признаком для переходного глагола является возможность присоединения существительного в форме В.п. Мы не можем сказать "напиться чай", поэтому "напиться" - непереходный глагол.